# How can I inline this progressbar to function for gmail?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

I have the code for a progress bar (snippet below) that I am not sure how I could go about inlining. I have already inlined the rest of my CSS for the rest of the template in which this progress bar will be found, as it was as simple as including 'style' in the `<div>`.

However, since gmail immediately removes `<style>` from `<head>`, and I do not see any properties for classes like `.done` or `.after`, I am not entirely sure how to proceed here.

I would appreciate any help with this problem, pointers for proper practices, or resources that may educate me further.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}

.progressbar li {
  /*name of incomplete tasks */
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  /*circle of incomplete tasks */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  content: "";
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative; /* ---------------- Added */
  z-index: 1; /* ------------------------ Added */
}

.progressbar li:after {
  /* line preceding incomplete tasks */
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 12px;
  left: -50%;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.done {
  /* check mark and name of completed tasks */
  color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.done:before {
  /* circles of completed tasks */
  border-color: #55b776;
  content: "\2713";
}

.progressbar li.done+li:after {
  /* line following completed tasks */
  background-color: #55b776;
}
</style>
</head>
  <table width="95%" align="center" cellpadding="10" style="width:95%;background-color:white;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="text-align: center;">
          <span class="container">
            <ul class="progressbar">
              <li class="done">Open</li>
              <li class="done">In Progress</li>
              <li>With Engineering</li>
              <li>Resolution Provided</li>
              <li>Closed</li>
            </ul>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I pretty sure that gmail doesn’t support pseudo elements such as :before and :after.